# Create a struct from a random input string

Tags: c++

I am wondering, is it possible to create any struct from a random input string in C++? For example, if I input a string:

`1, "apple", 2`

then I would like to have a struct:

`struct{int, string, int}`

If I input:

`"a", "b", 1`

Then I would like to have a struct:

`struct{string, string, int}`

So, the struct would be defined dynamically, based on the input string. Is there any method for doing this in C++?

Comment: Both C and C++ are *compiled* languages. Structure are defined in the source, and once the source has been compiled it's not possible to create new structure types. With that said, you could create a set of data structures that handle input of different kinds, it's what just about any text-parsing system does. If you want more specific details you need to tell us the *actual* and *underlying* problem you're trying to solve. If you don't ask about your actual problem directly, your question becomes an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: You could parse it and create `std::tuple`s like `std::tuple<int, std::string, int>` or `std::tuple<std::string, std::string, int>` etc.

Comment: No. That is a container, such as a `std::vector` with `std::variant` in.

Comment: If you want a container like @CostantinoGrana suggests, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3a5r41djY) may be a start

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wow! I'm so bad with functional programming that the `std::visit` really blew me away. Why not making an answer of that Godbolt link? It's really a good example.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Thanks! I'm a bit hesitant to posting it as an answer. OP haven't even commented on it so it's probably not what OP wants after all.